# Initialization list for vector of function pointers in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, function-pointers

I'm attempting to codify a DFA using a table of function pointers.

The table is populated by function pointers to functions to either output something or move to another state in the table, all based off what input the machine receives.

Right now what I can do is

```
function<token* ()> A1 = bind(A, &data);
function<token* ()> A2 = bind(B, &data);
function<token* ()> S1 = bind(S, 1);
function<token* ()> S2 = bind(S, 2);

vector< function<token* ()> > _table = { A1, A2, S1, S2 };
```

To make a 2x2 "table" where [0][0] performs action A1, [0][1] performs actions A2, [1][0] does shift to row 1, [1][1] does a shift to row 2... and so on.

My question is, in c++11, is there any faster way to do this? My state table has grown to 60x150, I have 50 different actions all bound to different functions, and I have to define a shift function to get to each row.

I'm trying to do this all in C++11's initialization features so it is done at compile time rather than at run time.

Is it possible to create a macro or something that performs something like:

```
vector<function<token* ()> > S;
for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
  function<token* ()> S[i] = bind(S, i);
}
```

so that after that I can reference `S[3]` or whatever and it gives me back the appropriately bound function pointer?

Comment: Have you considered boost meta state machine at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html

Comment: I had never heard of that before. I shall look into it later tonight. Thank you for the link!

Comment: What do you mean by 'faster'? Faster to write? Faster to execute? Also as long as you're using `std::function` you won't be able to have the initialization occur at compile time.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to faster to write. It was getting to be a pain having to write out and bind functions for every state transition possible. Why doesn't it initialize at compile time? I don't really understand whats going on I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) you can make some easily:

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>
struct token{};
token* S(int){return new token;}
#define MAKE_FUNCT(z, n, unused)         \
BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n)                     \
std::bind(S, n)                          \

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::function<token* ()>> table = 
                  {BOOST_PP_REPEAT(10, MAKE_FUNCT, ~)};
}
```

Here is an [example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/419oaX%2410), passing the `-E` flag I get:

```
std::vector<std::function<token* ()>> table = { std::bind(S, 0) , std::bind(S, 1) , std::bind(S, 2) , std::bind(S, 3) , std::bind(S, 4) , std::bind(S, 5) , std::bind(S, 6) , std::bind(S, 7) , std::bind(S, 8) , std::bind(S, 9)};
```